# How to calculate height of browser menubar,toolbar,navigation bar , bookmark using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate height of browser using jquery so that i can set my another div element accordingly . So what do I have to do in order to make it work???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `.height()` method present in the jquery which will give you a height of the different element

to find height of the browser or your HTML document than write

`$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport

$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document`

Comment: @yagesh_agola: yes it will return window height.suppose initially browser is expanded it will give 600 height. then if resize window and refresh window it will give less than 600 hight. i want same height i.e 600. so that it looks same as original.

Comment: @Raje: it means that you want your initial height of the windows after resize window?

Comment: than you need to store it in global variable to use it.